Triggering an explicit state-machine event in a before_ filter
I have an ActiveRecord model using the state-machines gem.
In it, I wish to trigger an event in a before_validation or before_save callback:
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  state_machine initial: :pending do
    event :complete do
      transition pending: :complete, if: :some_guard_clause?
    end

    event :fail do
      transition pending: :failed, if: :some_other_guard_clause?
    end
  end

  before_validation :attempt_transitions

  private

  def attempt_transitions
    self.state_event = "complete" if can_complete?
    self.state_event = "fail" if can_fail?
  end
end

However

setting self.state_event apparently has no effect inside before_ callbacks
I have verified that attempt_transitions is called and correctly sets state_event, but the state does not change on save. Presumably because state-machines only checks for this at the beginning of its around filter, which is already past at this point

just setting the Model#state= directly does not trigger state machine callbacks
This is not shown in my example, but I rely on before_transition and after_transition callbacks provided by state-machines. Those do not trigger when assigning a state directly.

triggering an update with #complete / #complete! instead of self.state_event leads to infinite recursion
... which I think is probably a fair thing to happen when one tries to save inside a save

moving to an after_save callback is not an option for me
... because it would mean performing twice the UPDATEs and twice the side effects (callbacks to other models)


How does one dynamically trigger events from inside before_ callbacks?

Thanks @engineersmnky, unfortunately not - the state-machines event lifecycle seems to happen before all validations, so simply being the first makes no difference here. And what I want, in a word: initiate a state machine event from inside a before_ callback.

I noticed that you mention leaving out details. Can you possibly provide an example of the actual desired implementation and result? Is there are reason the transitions cannot occur within the state machine and must be triggered outside?

Yes. Imagine the model having multiple boolean flag attributes; when all of them have eventually become true, the state machine is supposed to change its state - think "Payment received? Check. Invoice sent? Also check. Order is now complete".

Those all seem like state changes so I guess I am asking why you can't have events or transitions for that. E.g. state :invoice_sent { transition to: :complete, on: :payment_received } ? or transition [:invoice_sent, :payment_received] => :complete, if: ->(order) {order.can_complete?}

This was simply an example, the actual conditions are not states, and they cannot be, because they are not fulfilled in any particular fixed order. My question is how do I trigger state events from this specific point in the lifecycle of an ActiveRecord object?. Please just take it on faith that doing so is indeed necessary.
